# gridView to have countdown from 120 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On click of a button, it redirects using a session variable to another page and displays the loaded data in a gridview. Now this gridview should have a column for countdown of 120 seconds and disables the hyperlink as it expires.

Similarly when another user hits the same button from a different page, it should start the count down in the same gridview and so on.

Any help will be really thankful using C# and asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_booker" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="countdown">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <h1 id="timest" style="text-align: center"></h1>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                var milisec = 0
                var seconds = 120
                document.getElementById("timest").innerHTML = '120'
                function display()
                   {
                       if (milisec <= 0) {milisec = 9 seconds -= 1}
                       if (seconds <= -1) {milisec = 0 seconds += 1}
                       else
                       milisec -= 1                                     
                       document.getElementById("timest").innerHTML = seconds
                       setTimeout(display, 1000)
                   }
                display(
           </script>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: This sounds like a great project.  I suggest you post code of what you've already attempted and any errors you've received.  SO is not a "do this thing for me" kind of site.

Answer (score 0):

A little more specific detail regarding the app would be great, but as far as the "gridview should have a column for countdown of 120 seconds and disables the hyperlink as it expires." is concerned it is very simple.

You just need to maintain a Timer , and on its Tick you make the countdown visible in the gridview column , once it reaches to 120 secs than you can disable/enable your hyperlink.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume you are doing this as a webform etc.

All you need to look up is manipulating controls via a timer. Since the code is rendered out as html (ie your c# does not affect the webpage once its rendered). This means you have to use 'javascript' to achieve this.

In the java script you have 3 things.

1. A reference to the form control
2. The timer that executes a bit of code
3. The actual code to do what you want (in your case the hyperlink change)

If this is not a webform but a winform then you could have an async task which runs the code to execute the changes to the form control.

Form control = buttons, textboxes, gridview, listview etc.

Comment: Then this is way you have to deal with this problem Kamal. You must use a javascript function that does the timer and exectures your code that disables the hyperlinks.